# Ckeditor and Kcfinder issue

Tags: php, cakephp, ckeditor, kcfinder

In CakePHP, I use the integration between CKEDITOR and KCFINDER. the problem is when I browse to upload the image It shows me like this image below:
[image]

So I cannot see the folder default (images) at left and no action when clicked on Upload.
Please show me the solution.

Comment: Check your Javascript console. Any problems there?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `ckfinder/config.php`   `$baseUrl` is wrong. Please check it.

And my is `$baseUrl = '/files/';`  Hope I can help you: http://www.icode100.com/posts/view/10